# Panel Data with three identifiers

Tags: stata, panel-data

My panel dataset consists of three identifiers:

1. Country
2. Industry
3. Year

I would like to calculate the effects of a variable `X` across different industries.

I am confused how I should treat in Stata the panel dimension (identifier) since standard panel data techniques treats are two dimensional (`i`, `t`).

For example, if I want to run a fixed effects and random effects model to check the effects of a variable `X` across industries, what is the correct approach in this case?

Should i go with:

```
xtset country
```

or:

```
xtset country industry
```

Comment: You should always include a [mcve] with your question.

Answer (score 2):

You can do the following:

```
egen id = group(country industry)
xtset id year
```

Comment: I have a question about how the grouping works. It's my understanding that by using `egen`, `group`, you are effectively creating a panel for each combination of the two variables. Then, does this mean that the actual effect that is being accounted for is the effect that the industry had in a given country? It seems to me that you are assuming that the effects of an industry are country-specific, something that is not necessarily true. All I want to check is how a variable `x` affects industry `i` regardless the country in which the industry is.

Comment: @msh855 your question in its current form essentially asks how you can undertake panel data analysis with all three dimensions. At least that is how i understood it. Otherwise it is off-topic since it is more of a statistical question and not a programming one.

Comment: @msh855 in the former case, my answer offers one approach but i did not say it is necessarily correct. It all depends what your research question really is and what you mean by "panel" (i.e. how you define it).

Comment: Yes, is more of a statistical question, but nevertheless relates how I could implement my problem in Stata.

Comment: You can also `xtset` in terms of industry alone. But you're then implicitly assuming that all variations within industry in terms of country and year are equivalent. That sounds unlikely too. Mixed model?